# What kind of work/income is doable for one with social ineptitude but not qualifying for disability benefits?

Tags: income, law, disability

Say someone has like autism or just social issues, but their specific case is not enough to qualify them for benefits.

What is the alternative? If no one gives you money but you can't steadily make it yourself, isn't homelessness/theft all there is?

Assuming one has no financial support/family/etc. this situation is even darker as nobody will help can or will help you.

So what is the solution? One unable to hold a job but cannot otherwise qualify for benefits. Is crime the only way, friends?

Answer (score 3):

This is a recognized challenge, but there are resources available. According to the [US Department of Labor](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/odep/program-areas/autism):

> Employers have increasingly focused on expanding efforts to improve access to employment for job candidates on the autism spectrum to tap their diverse talents. Many large and small employers have adjusted their recruitment, hiring, and onboarding policies and practices to increase access for this population.

According to [Verywell Health](https://www.verywellhealth.com/things-you-need-to-know-about-autism-and-employment-4159850):

> As the population of adults diagnosed with autism grows, resources and programs are becoming available for those entering adulthood... To help determine an individual's best career choices, school counselors and agency personnel can use tools such as vocational and aptitude tests... Many large corporations have begun to see the value of hiring employees on the autism spectrum.

[Autism Speaks](https://www.autismspeaks.org/blog/12-steps-help-adults-autism-find-right-job), among other tips, points to a [website](https://www.thespectrumcareers.com/)

> designed by and for job seekers with autism to connect with businesses that are looking to hire individuals on the spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

The precise nature of the welfare system varies from place to place, so it depends where you are, but taking the UK as an example: regardless of whether you qualify for disability benefits, if your income is low enough (due to not having any job or having a very low paying job) you may still be entitled to claim various benefits. There will be restrictions and limits on these, for example you may need to show that you are actively searching for a job. The Citizens Advice service or various other charitable organisations can help you navigate the system and determine what you are eligible to claim for.

I also want to slightly refute your premise. There are many many “traditional” jobs that can be done by people with autism or “social issues” as you put it. It might be that you have to look outside the expected normal pathways for someone with your education level or find a career counsellor who can help you determine what jobs would be suited for.

Even if you cannot find a single advertised job vacancy that you feel you could do, there are plenty of ways to make money that aren’t crime. They might require a lot of hard work, though. Any skill or talent you have can be put to use by people who don’t have that talent - for example if you can make websites then you can set yourself up offering website development services for small businesses. If you are physically fit you can offer services as a garden labourer or odd job person. If you can play computer games really well you can enter esports tournaments for prize money. And so on… again a career counsellor or specialist charity that works with people with social disabilities could help you find options that would be most well suited to your particular skills.